# How are VBScript parentheses expressions named/parsed?

Tags: vbscript

I'm building an AST format for a VBScript parser. Now I need to add a format to the AST indicating "MemberExpression", where a object is indexed with a value that refers to its property, e.g:

```
' member expression
( object.prop )
' computed member expression
( object("prop") )
```

A object can be normally indexed with a **`.`**, but my confusion is at the computed indexing with **`(...)`** because:

- the optional arguments list of sub/function can be enclosed with parenthesis (**`function(argList)`**). Note: I know arguments list doesn't need to be enclosed with parentheses.

If I treat any parentheses expressions as computed member expressions it'll be wrong if a sub/function call includes **argList** that is enclosed with parentheses, e.g:

```
Sub fnc(msg)
    MsgBox msg:::
End Sub

fnc("Hello") ' this call statement will be treated as member expression
' but should be treated as a call statement
```

So, my real question is: does VBScript parser need to know that **`fnc`** is a function/sub to set its appropriate AST format? How does the original VBScript parser handles a call statement?

Comment: Possibly you need to use [`GetRef()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekabbe10(v=vs.84).aspx)? Failing that where's [@eric-lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) when you need him??

Comment: @Lankymart I don't know this man, err

Comment: @TheProHands Lankymart comment will be sent to eric so he'll know this question exists. He is the last programmer that wrote anything significant in the VBS codebase.

Comment: @Noodles: And that was a long, long time ago. :-)

Comment: @TheProHands: VBScript can be a tricky language to parse correctly.  If you want to test out corner cases in your parser, I did a silly little quiz on some of the odder cases back in 2005. The answers begin here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/02/18/vbscript-quiz-answers-part-one/

Comment: @EricLippert Thx, Erik! That's very helpful for my future parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric's work is available without him.

> Here’s the deal: parentheses mean several different things in VB and hence in VBScript. They mean:
>
> 1) Evaluate a subexpression before the rest of the expression: Average = (First + Last) / 2
>
> 2) Dereference the index of an array: Item = MyArray(Index)
>
> 3) Call a function or subroutine: Limit = UBound(MyArray)
>
> 4) Pass an argument which would normally be byref as byval: Result = MyFunction(Arg1, (Arg2)) ‘ Arg1 is passed byref, arg2 is passed byval
>
> That’s confusing enough already. Unfortunately, VB and hence VBScript has some weird rules about when #3 applies. The rules are
>
> 3.1) An argument list for a function call with an assignment to the returned value must be surrounded by parens: Result = MyFunc(MyArg)
>
> 3.2) An argument list for a subroutine call (or a function call with no assignment) that uses the Call keyword must be surrounded by parens: Call MySub(MyArg)
>
> 3.3) If 3.1 and 3.2 do not apply then the list must NOT be surrounded by parens.

From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/

Comment: This answered my question, however I'm not still sure about how can I name the parenthesis expression, do you have a short idea?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `object("prop")` would generally be a collection (in which case it should be plural - objects) using the default property of the collection - `item` and asking for the thing called `prop`.

Comment: Yes, but... if it's a collection indexing, I can't name `func(args)` a collection indexing because `func` is a sub/function and is being called.

Comment: We program here not do conceptual stuff. This is the conceptual site - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is the VBA spec that VBS is 99.9% based on. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no

```
' computed member expression
( object("prop") )
```

in VBScript. Evidence:

```
Option Explicit

Class c
  Dim p
End Class

Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d("p") = "quoted key name works for dictionary"
WScript.Echo d("p")

Dim o : Set o = New c
o.p = ". prop name works for object"
WScript.Echo o.p
Dim s : s = "quoted prop name does not work for object"
On Error Resume Next
  o("p") = s
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
On Error GoTo 0
WScript.Echo s
```

output:

```
cscript 39757881.vbs
quoted key name works for dictionary
. prop name works for object
Object doesn't support this property or method
quoted prop name does not work for object
```

Comment: But in my example **`object`** would really be a scripting dictionary, I forgot to mention that. I'm not costumed with VBScript language, I'm not very familiar with everything on VBScript. I learned somethings with your answer, however it doesn't answer to the way parentheses are parsed or handled, for example, how is `function():` parsed (this is a call with arguments list enclosed by parenthesis)?

Comment: It is a function so must have a return variable to assign it to. This is what VBScript will do. It is ambiguous so VBS always assumed it to be a function. `a = func(a,(b))` it can tell so 1st param byref and second byval. This is handled in point 4 of my post.

Comment: @Noodles Yum... I think I got it. You tried to say that `object("prop")` is a call that is being assigned with a new value, right (for example, the return value of that call can be re-assigned)?. Please let me know, thx

Comment: You can't tell without the whole line.